# How to remove older files, folder & subfolders in linux?

Tags: linux

I have managed to remove files older than X days in my centos, but the folders still remains and gets a time stamped of the current date.

My current command is

```
find /home/Dropbox/mysqldump/ -type f -mtime +120 -exec rm {} +
```

my folder structure is like mysqldump>2015>02>01, 02, 03 etc..

Comment: You tagged this Linux, use GNU's `-delete` flag.

Answer (score 1):

You are telling `find` to only find files, not directories. Try removing the `-type f` directive.

Comment: still does not remove the folder in the end of tree

Comment: @Tapash This isn't a script-writing service...play around with it until it works. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to prune regularly, just use one base folder and name your dumps appropriately. I tend to use `$(date +\%F.\%T)` as part of the file name.